# Deletar elemento da fila e liberar memoria para esta função?

Tags: c, ponteiro, fila

Estou começando a entender melhor ponteiros e estou implementando uma fila, e segue a função:

```
FILA *removeNodeFIFO(FILA **raiz)
{
    FILA *aux = *raiz;
    if (aux == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (aux->prox == NULL)
        {

            *raiz = NULL;
            return aux;
        }
        else
        {
            *raiz = aux->prox;
            return aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Estou passando a raiz por referencia, já que tenho que atualizar a raiz e retornar o elemento deletado, mas não sei como faria para retornar o elemento deletado e depois desalocar da memória, para isso precisaria usar o free(aux) logo após o return, como posso liberar depois de retornado?

Fazendo deste modo, estou liberando ela? supondo que estou chamando ela em outra função:

```
FILA *cel = removeNodeFIFO(&raiz);
...Faço o que preciso com o nó retornado...
free(cel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, está liberando! Pode checar os endereços com printf("%p");

Coloca um:

```
printf("%p\n", aux);
```

antes de retorná-lo, e um:

```
printf("%p\n", cel);
```

antes de dar free, pra você ver que trata-se do mesmo endereço.